# Recyclerview Edittext data loss on scroll

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, notifydatasetchanged

I am trying to implement recyclerview which have a 50-100 list of item. Each row contains of TextView and Edittext view. User type comments on each row containing edittext. But the issue is that when user types the value and try to scroll up/down, data entered in the row get lost.

Then I tried another solution. I update the value of the array at that position and notifyDataSetChanged, it prints value on all row containing edittext

My Adapter:

```
class MyAdapter(
    val context: Context,
    val itemList: MutableList<String>
) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    
    class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        var txtLabel: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.txtLabel)
        var etValue: EditText = view.findViewById(R.id.etValue)
        var watcher: TextWatcher? = null
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): ViewHolder {
        val view =
            LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_comment, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.txtLabel.text = itemList[position]
        holder.watcher = holder.etValue.doAfterTextChanged { text ->
            try {
                updateItem(
                    position,
                    text.toString()
                )

            } catch (ex: Exception) {
                println(ex.message)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return itemList.size
    }

    fun updateItem(position: Int, item: String) {
        itemList.add(position, item)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

When updateItem method run it updates all rows but I am passing the position to only update at that position. Kindly guide what is the issue.

Comment: In `updateItem` : I think you meant `itemList.set(position, item)`, not `itemList.add(position, item)`.
`notifyDataSetChanged()`  seems unnecessary.

Comment: add will do the same if we pass the index with it. It add value at given index

Comment: But thus you generate more and more items in your recycler. Is that what you intend? Every time you insert a character in your EditText, you add a new item to the recyler with current EditText's value.

Comment: Yes your point is valid. But it also changing color of textview where user entered the input. In that case I have to notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: You could use `etValue.onFocusChangeListener` to change TexView's color. (There's only one focused view at a time)

Answer (score 1):

`holder.etValue.doAfterTextChanged` will add a `TextChangedListener`. You don't remove it later and thus you end up with multiple listener attached to one EditText.

You could rewrite your code like this:

```
class MyAdapter(
    val context: Context,
    val itemList: MutableList<String>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        lateinit var onTextUpdated: (String) -> Unit
        var txtLabel: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.txtLabel)
        var etValue: EditText = view.findViewById(R.id.etValue)

        init { // TextChanged listener added only once.
            etValue.doAfterTextChanged { editable ->
                val text = editable.toString()
                onTextUpdated(text)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): ViewHolder {
        val view =
       LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_comment, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.txtLabel.text = itemList[position]
        holder.onTextUpdated = { text -> // each time holder is bound, new listener will be assigned
            try {
                updateItem(
                    position,
                    text
                ) // update cached value
                holder.txtLabel.text = text // update label

            } catch (ex: Exception) {
                println(ex.message)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return itemList.size
    }

    fun updateItem(position: Int, item: String) {
        itemList[position] = item
        // this might mess up the EditTexts focus. 
        // notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

Comment: Its giving me error onTextUpdated has not been initialized

Comment: You must have modified it incorrectly. `onTextUpdated` property has to be set before accessing it.

Comment: Yes, I did that. Thanks for the help bro